# Setting text color in a StyleableTextField

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5, flex4.6, flex-mobile

Please advise me, how to set the text color in a [StyleableTextField](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/StyleableTextField.html).

The following doesn't work for me (the color stays black):

```
  tf.setStyle('color', 0xFF0000);
```

And this too:

```
  tf.setStyle('color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StyleableTextField` has a `textColor` property. Try using that. 
(`tf.textColor = 0xFF0000;`).

However, I found that in my ItemRenderers I sometimes need to use both the `textColor` property and the setStyle to properly change colors of StylableTextFields. Don't really know why, yet.

Comment: Thank you, I had missed that property